# how can i solve the unique field error in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, unique, rules

```
'call_signs' => [
    'required', 'array', 'min:1',
    'call_signs.*.call_sign' => [
        Rule::unique('call_signs', 'call_sign')->whereNull('deleted_at')->ignore($user->id, 'user_id')
    ]
],
```

this is my unique code 
it gives me the error

call_signs is an array

> BadMethodCallException
>   Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateUnique:callSigns,callSign,"12",userId,deletedAt,"NULL" does not exist.

my Callsign table has softDelete

Comment: Can you show your model?

Comment: namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class CallSign extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'call_sign',
        'default_flag'
    ];


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}@Darick

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's Unique Validation Rule provides only `ignore` method and not `whereNull` method. Please note that `whereNull` method is part of Database Query Builder.

Also, it is usually not good to check for uniqueness on soft deletes on tables. You should consider using hard delete for such use case.

Anyway, if you want to use for some reason, you can create your own unique custom validation rule. You can read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#custom-validation-rules), contains example also.

Comment: i've removed the whereNull from the rule but still its not working